# C++ How do I print an object?

Tags: c++

I have created a constructor

```
Location(double xIn,double yIn,string placeIn,int timeIn)
: x(xIn),y(yIn) ...so on {
```

Say I want to print Location home(x,y,place,time); that's in the `main()`.

How would I do so? I've been searching around and was told to use `operator<<`. How would I implement this?

**UPDATE:** After creating some get methods and I tried doing,can't exactly compile it because of the problem

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream & o, const Location & rhs){

        o << rhs.getX() << "," << rhs.getY() << "," << rhs.getPlace() << "," << rhs.getTime();
        return o; }
```

Comment: Your title and your question bear no relationship to one another. As for your question, keep studying and reading until you find an example and explanation of how to write your own stream insertion operator; there are tens of thousands available to choose from.

Comment: I just realised I did not finish writing my title before writing my question....

Comment: "_would that be the right thing to do?"_ Well, did it do what you wanted?

Comment: No it did not... I was asking if I was on the right track.

Comment: I recommend using more meaningful variable names than `lhs` (left hand side) or `rhs` (right hand side).

Comment: So in what way did it not? Come on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the stencil for overloading `operator<<`:

```
class Any
{
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Any& a);
  private:
    int member;
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Any& a)
{
  output << a.member;
  return output;
}
```

This one possible stencil, there are other possibilities.  Search the internet for "c++ stream insertion operator overload example" for other implementations.